# Need to have type-safety for more than 22 fields. Any workarounds?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Have 23 fields in a table.(Cannot avoid, don't want to normalize it more for performance reasons)

Any workarounds to achieve type-safety for more than 22 fields using JOOQ?

Comment: Could you provide an example query where you would like to see the additional type safety?

Answer (score 1):

What about using views to access the table instead?

Define multiple separate views, each with different sets of columns from the underlying table and with a reasonable number of columns.